# How to query products where the combined price and quantity is less than another

Tags: mysql

I have this sample services table where I maintain a records of massage services that I sell as product.

```
||ID||Duration||Price||
|1  |100      |10.0|
|2  |200      |20.0|
|3  |300      |30.0|
|4  |400      |25.0|
|5  |500      |50.0|
```

Overtime, I add new products(combination of price and duration) that are more competitive than the existing ones to attract more customers.
I want to find outdated records. It is considered outdated when you need pay more and get less. In the above example the record with ID 3 is outdated.

How do I write the query to achieve this?

Comment: well, how do we know which rows are outdated by which other(s)? You mention that ID 3 is outdated...but which row do you consider to have replaced it? 4, I guess? You could write something to detect this, but it might get complicated if there's more than one outdated service in there at once. A better design might be to add an extra column where you explicitly specify the ID which the new record is replacing. That way, you can find records to delete (or maybe just hide from your results) much more simply, and you have, for your analysis, a clear trail of the changes to your business.

Comment: @ADyson outdated means a price higher than any massage that has a duration equal or higher. You don't want to pay 30 for a 300 duration massage when you can pay 25

Comment: If you take the ration of price and duration, you will see that ID 4 is the cheapest and therefore all the others are "outdated", you get less for your money with them.

Comment: @Cid I figured that, but thought it might be awkward if say there were 3 new products, to work out precisely which previous one(s) they nullify. I admit I haven't thought it through fully, so maybe it doesn't cause an issue.

Comment: @stickybit no they aren't. if you want a 200 seconds duration massage, you don't want to pay 25, but 20

Comment: @Cid: And if I want 800 I don't take 8 100 or 4 200 for a total of 80 but two 400 for a total of 50. Does that "outdate" the 100 and 200 then?

Comment: If you want 800 you get twice the 400. But if a client has only 10 or 20, he couldn't use the service since those massages were removed. That's why they can't be considered as outdated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An outdated massage is a massage that has a price higher than any massage that has a duration higher

The outdated massages can be retrieved using this kind of query :

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM massages m1
JOIN massages m2
ON m1.Price > m2.Price
AND m1.Duration <= m2.Duration
```

And then, this query can be used to find the massages to delete in a `DELETE` query :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE massages (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `Duration` INTEGER,
  `Price` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO massages
  (`ID`, `Duration`, `Price`)
VALUES
  (1, 100, 10.0),
  (2, 200, 20.0),
  (3, 300, 30.0),
  (4, 400, 25.0),
  (5, 500, 50.0);

-- -------------------------- This is what you are looking for --------------------------
DELETE FROM massages
WHERE massages.ID IN
(
    SELECT id FROM
    (
      SELECT m1.ID AS id
      FROM massages m1
      JOIN massages m2
      ON m1.Price > m2.Price
      AND m1.Duration <= m2.Duration
    ) AS IdsToDelete
);
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM massages;
```

Output

```
| ID  | Duration | Price |
| --- | -------- | ----- |
| 1   | 100      | 10    |
| 2   | 200      | 20    |
| 4   | 400      | 25    |
| 5   | 500      | 50    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kCzEVCHrJzdvXhb3TXNP8F/0)